# Which verb should be used instead of "involve" here?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

In an academic writing, I have such sentences:

This field of study **involves** several concerns. Among many others, we focus on two of them which is more related to our research in the next subsection.

It seems "involve" is not a suitable word here. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: How about this rephrasing— "_This field of study entails several concerns; however, we shall focus on two of them that are more related to our research in the next subsection._"

Comment: @user405662 two questions? 1. Does usage of 'involve' in my sentence is correct? 2. what does 'entail' mean here? I want a word that shows several issues in this field of study should be cared and we want only to talk about two of them only.

Comment: I'm afraid there are various errors in this question. 'Many' is a lot more than 'several', for a start. But focusing on the sentence 'This field of study involves several concerns.' I'd rephrase as 'In this field [of study], there are many/several issues we must/might address.'

Comment: *This field of study **addresses** several **concerns**,* whereas ***That** field of study **covers / involves / incorporates** several **disciplines**.*

Comment: I don’t see what’s wrong with ***involves***.  There are many more glaring errors in the rest of that sentence that need to be addressed before worrying about replacing *involves*.

Comment: @Jim Since I'm not a native English speaker, can you name some of those glaring errors?